# Data argument not used by format string

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

following the videos on lynda's objective c i've ran intro a small problem,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Player.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {


    Player *p = [[Player alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"The score is @i", [p score]); <-- Data argument not used by format string

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the signature (return type) for Player.score()? Also, I don't see any format specifiers of the type "@i".. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.htmlperhaps you are looking for "@d" ?

Comment: @ForhadAhmed The problem is that format specifiers begin with `%`, not `@`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have a valid format string. You want `%i`, not `@i`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `NSLog(@"The score is %i", [p score]);`

`score` returns integer so `%i` or `%d` should be used not `@i`

Answer (score 2):

If value returned by [p score] is an integer then it should be
NSLog(@"The score is **%i**", [p score]);  // Always use '%' as format specifier not '@'

Answer (score 2):

The format string should use `%i` instead of `@i`:

```
NSLog(@"The score is %i", [p score]);
```